# Undefined index : product_image

Tags: php, arrays, post, undefined-index

I was trying to build form to to get product and this error came.

> Notice: Undefined index: product_image in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\Admin_area\insert_product.php on line 159
>
> Notice: Undefined index: product_image in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\Admin_area\insert_product.php on line 160
>   insert into products
>   (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keyword)
>   values ('1','1','HP laptop','2000',' dasdasdda
>
> ','','asda')

PS: I know it's repeated question but I still can't solve it.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<?php 

include("includes/db.php");

?>

<html>
<head>

    <title>Inserting Product</title>

    <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="skyblue">

    <form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">

        <table align="center" width="700px" border="2px" bgcolor="Green">

            <tr align="center">

                <td colspan="7"><h2>Insert New Product</h2></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Title*</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_title" size="40" required=""></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Category</b></td>
                <td>

                <select name="product_cat" required="">

                    <option>Select Category</option>

                    <?php 

                        $get_cats = "select * from categories";
                        $run_cats = mysqli_query($con, $get_cats);

                        while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

                            $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
                            $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];

                            echo "<option value='$cat_id'>$cat_title</option>";

                            }

                     ?>

                </select>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Brand</b></td>
                <td>

                    <select name="product_brand" required="">

                    <option>Select Brand</option>

                    <?php 

                        $get_brand = "select * from brands";
                        $run_brand = mysqli_query($con, $get_brand);

                        while ($row_brand = mysqli_fetch_array($run_brand)) {

                            $brand_id = $row_brand['brand_id'];
                            $brand_title = $row_brand['brand_title'];

                            echo "<option value='$brand_id'>$brand_title</option>";

                            }

                     ?>

                </select>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Image</b></td>
                <td><input type="file" name="product_image"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Price</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_price" required=""></td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Description</b></td>
                <td><textarea name="product_desc" cols="20" rows="10"></textarea> </td>

            </tr>

            <tr>

                <td align="center"><b>Product Keyword</b></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="product_keyword" size="40" required=""></td>

            </tr>

            <tr align="center">

                <td colspan="7"><input type="submit" name="insert_post" value="Insert Now" required=""></td>

            </tr>

        </table>


    </form>


</body>
</html>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){

        //Getting Text

        $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
        $product_keyword = $_POST['product_keyword'];

        //Getting Image

        $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

        //Inserting Data

        echo $insert_product = "insert into products (product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keyword) values ('$product_cat','$product_brand','$product_title','$product_price','$product_desc','$product_image','$product_keyword')";

    }

 ?>
```

Comment: Where is that line 159 in your code?

Comment: And btw: that is not an error, but a _notice_...

Comment: Undefined index of... It means that `product_image` is not part of the array, either `$_POST` or `$_FILE`. So your first step into fixing this would be to see if you are actually posting the values before asking for them.

Comment: line 159 :  $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];

Comment: @NamanShrivastava check my answer below it will help you

Comment: Okk then just update the table then ask to look at it....@Samuel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have miss-spelled the `enctype` value in the form:

change

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/formdata">
```

to

```
<form action="insert_product.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: thnxx B.desai...i did the correction...and updated data in table...and it worked...thank you..